# Installed ubuntu on wrong hard drive, how do I remove?

Tags: installation, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I have a 128gb SSD with Windows 7 installed and a 500gb disk partioned into 100gb and 400gb. I incorrectly installed Ubuntu on the 400gb partition and as a result have no option to select Ubuntu as an operating system when I boot up my pc.

I understand there is an issue when removing Linux due to something about GRUB loader, can I simply format the HDD (contains nothing of importance) containing linux and be gone with it as Windows 7 is on a different disk altogether and I never actually accessed Ubuntu?

I am hoping I am overcomplicating things for myself, please can someone point me in the right direction!

Comment: Where do you want Ubuntu to be? Do you want it to share the SSD with Windows 7? Do you want to put it in the 100GB partition of the HDD? **Please edit the original question** with the answer.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/204821/partitions-for-ubuntu-and-windows-7-dual-boot-on-ssd-hdd-setup if you want to setup Windows and Ubuntu both in the SSD. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/193807/installing-ubuntu-on-one-of-two-hard-drives if you want to setup Ubuntu in HDD and keep the SSD for Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot your PC as usual, what happens? If it boots to Windows normally, feel free to format the disk with Ubuntu, and reinstall. However, there is a better solution - teach your Windows to boot into Ubuntu. [Here is instruction.](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/2/) In any case, [read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) too.

Answer (score 0):

run the installation again making sure you format the incorrect hard drive in the driver selection process then install Ubuntu on the correct hard drive