# help with installation wizard and ssd

Tags: system-installation, ssd, partitioning

I want to switch from win8 to Ubuntu but I'm stuck on the installation wizard partition management.

I've a 24gb ssd and a 750gb hdd, and I would like to have the "core" on the ssd and data on hdd, for maximum performances

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partitions for Ubuntu and Windows 7 dual boot on SSD + HDD setup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204821/partitions-for-ubuntu-and-windows-7-dual-boot-on-ssd-hdd-setup). Also see [Do I need Intel Smart Response when installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

When the wizarad asks you what you want to do, choose "Something else" option.

[image]

Then you can manually allocate space for your partitions manually.

[image]

The "core" is called ROOT in linux. It is indicated as **/**.

Mount it on your SSD.

Then define / home partition for your HDD.

Comment: I mount / on ALL the ssd and /home on ALL the hdd? what about /var, swap, /boot, etc?

Comment: allocate some of your hdd for swap (equal to the size of you RAM). Other things will be done by the setup software itself. You don't have to care about them.