# How do I setup Ubuntu for SSD and HDD?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a feeling that this question has been asked before, but I was wanting to know if anyone has installed Ubuntu on an SSD and have their /home folder on an HDD?

The reason I ask is I have a MacBook Pro that I recently upgraded to an SSD, I have my /Users folder on a separate hard drive from tips I have learned from watching YouTube videos.

I want to know if it can be done on Ubuntu as well, if it can, please provide easy to follow instructions for me to follow so when I get another SSD for a computer I built, I can do it and show my inner geek. LOL!

Remember, I want Ubuntu on the SSD and my /home folder on the HDD, this is NOT a dual-boot setup.

Stay Awesome and Always Believe

Comment: This has been answered before here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204821/partitions-for-ubuntu-and-windows-7-dual-boot-on-ssd-hdd-setup

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive

Answer (score 0):

when doing installation, select custom partitioning.

make partition on ssd, mount point / (or what ever you want) then on HDD make partition and set mountpoint as /home

Comment: I tried that with my current dual hard drive setup and the system failed to boot from the 250 GB hard drive. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I don't know. I may have to change the order of my drives to get it to work right. I'll try that method and see if it works. Thanks for your help. Stay Awesome and Always Believe.