# Installing Ubuntu on a device having both SSD and HDD completely fresh install

Tags: boot, system-installation

This might be a dumb question but I want to install ubuntu on SSD and I want to use the HDD as the rest of my storage. I mean like I currently have windows with a C drive on SSD and the rest of the drives on HDD. How can I do this for ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partitions for Ubuntu and Windows 7 dual boot on SSD + HDD setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204821/partitions-for-ubuntu-and-windows-7-dual-boot-on-ssd-hdd-setup)

Comment: Quite a few SSD+HHD computers uses RST instead of ACHI.  Ubuntu does not like RST if Windows also on it.  If computer uses RST and want keep Windows, google changing windows from RST to ACHI first, then can install Ubuntu the way you like.  Do not just change from RST to ACHI without preparing windows first.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system? Microsoft required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning since 2012, so most hardware is now UEFI. Even if BIOS, I often suggest gpt with new drives. I have done that since about 2010. But you need either a bios_grub for BIOS boot or ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot. I added both with BIOS system when planning a new UEFI system. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/whatsgpt.html

Comment: I always opt for "*Something else*" so I can tell the installer what I want, instead of having to choose from the offered options. That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the easiest will be to do a fully automated default install, where, however, you should make sure to use your fast SSD drive. That way, Ubuntu will create one partition on your SSD, that contains the system files and the user files (under the "/home" folder). In addition, a swap file will automatically be set up to be used as swap memory.

Your SSD will then host both your operating system and your daily work files for speedy access. You then can use your second drive for large files or extensive data such as movies, photo collections or audio, or for archiving data, etc.

By default, your other drive will be visible in the file manager. You need to click it there to have it mounted before you can access it. That can be fine if you use that drive only now and then. However, you may prefer it is available immediately. This requires a small system intervention after you finished installed the system. Nowadays, you can do that  using the "Disks" utility that is by default available in Ubuntu. The classical approach, however, is to manually add the drive to the system file `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Can you show what options to choose to make the operating system load on SSD and keep my HDD seperate