# Windows 10 dual boot ubuntu on ssd and data on hdd

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd, windows-10

I currently have windows 10 and I want to have ubuntu as second os, but I plan on using it more than windows, to get better at using the cli and linux in general. To have better performance I want to install ubuntu on my ssd, but because I don't have much room anymore (50GB), I want to store the data on my hdd. I saw another similar question but I couldn't understand everything there. I don't know enough about installing ubuntu.

These are some general questions I have:

- How big should the ubuntu partition on my ssd and hdd be?
- I don't know the meaning of all the options you get when installing ubuntu 
  (how do I know what's my ssd and hdd in the list of partitions?)
- What are the general steps to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: I use 25GB for / (root) but have all data on HDD in /mnt/data. If newer user easier just to put /home on HDD. Use Something Else install option. Post this: `sudo parted -l` from live installer's terminal. Similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/204821/partitions-for-ubuntu-and-windows-7-dual-boot-on-ssd-hdd-setup & using data partition: https://askubuntu.com/questions/118290/setup-for-dual-disk-ssdhdd-with-home-partition & http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage

Comment: @oldfred Thank you! Can I install ubuntu on my ssd and later put /home on my hdd or is that not possible?

Comment: You can move it: To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving If Windows 10 make sure fast start up is off. Is Windows UEFI. You want to be sure to install Ubuntu in same boot mode UEFI or BIOS as Windows is installed. And how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. You can mount NTFS partitions and easily read data. But often better/safer to separate Windows system from Windows data and only mount Windows system as read only.