# How do I divide my root partition into two partitions?

Tags: partitioning

I have been using Ubuntu 17.04 and it's the only operating system on my 500 GB hard-drive. I have only one partition (i.e root partition). Now I want to go back to 16.04 LTS but I want to keep my existing data intact so I want to create an additional partition to store my data(movies and the like) and reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 on the other partition. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Why are you going back to 16.04? Problems in 17.04? Ever consider 17.10?

Comment: I have multiple / (root) partitions of about 25GB  and mount my /mnt/data in all of them. Splitting home directory discussion and details:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811198 & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1901437 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/921778/windows-10-dual-boot-ubuntu-on-ssd-and-data-on-hdd If using ext4, you have to set ownership & permissions & mount with fstab.

Comment: @heynnema I am having trouble updating and upgrading apt resources. The repos are not working properly either. So, I am thinking of falling back to 16.04 and wait for 18.04..

Comment: @mikewhatever Didn't see the solution to my problem there, Mike.

Comment: Why not just boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and reinstall 17.04? That should take care of the apt/repo problem. Or... you could start a new question and try to get help fixing the existing apt/repo problem.

Comment: @heynnema no it won't - the repository problems are happening because 17.04 is EoL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you can do exactly what you want. The only way I see
is to save off all your personal files from the current 17.04, then
reinstall 16.04 on the entire disk and restore your files.
This is time-consuming, but should give you what you want.

Another, quicker option is a dual-boot scanario:

Boot from the 16.04 USB or DVD drive.
Tell it you want to Install 16.04

It will take you thru the installation and when you get to
the disk page, it will see the 17.04 system already there.

Tell it you want to install 16.04 beside 17.04 and choose
a lot of space for 16.04, making 17.04 very small.

This leaves you with both 16.04 and 17.04 sharing the 500GB
drive.

But, you can boot on 16.04 and read/write files on 17.04 and
vice-versa.

-mot

Comment: Thanks @mot. I decided to upgrade to 17.10, install Parrot OS alongside it and create a partition while doing that. But after upgrading to 17.10 and rebooting, I'm having  US 1-1.6 device descriptor errors..