# Storing data on second HDD, mounting

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have a new laptop with SSD + HDD. I already managed to set up a dual boot with Windows 10 preinstalled and Ubuntu 17.10. 
Ubuntu root, home and swap directories are all on the SSD. In addition I took 500GB from the HDD and created a partition for my data (I called it `/mnt`).

Now I want to make the operating system store music, downloads, documents, pictures and videos on the HDD data partition, while maintaining `/home` on the SSD.

I know it has to do with fstab, so I found the file and a way to edit it, but what am I supposed to do now? The general information is not clear enough for me.

Here is my fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
# / was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=cbdf87b9-ddf0-4242-a6b3-12ea1f13c653 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=7E53-EFDB  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
UUID=a78d2329-659f-4d6e-a7e3-c54f08dc5bdb /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /mnt was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=193e6f14-a677-4f3e-9373-06f6d12c12f0 /mnt            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=e8fe7608-591e-40b2-ab28-603b058c87f9 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Can someone guide me step by step?

Comment: I used to use NTFS for some data when I still had Windows, but now only have an ext4 /mnt/data partition. You may be better with /mnt/data as /mnt uses entire /mnt and cannot be used for other mnt. I also keep /home in / as so little data is still in it. NTFS shared on HDD
http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/921778/windows-10-dual-boot-ubuntu-on-ssd-and-data-on-hdd
 You also have to set ownership & permissions. Splitting home directory discussion and details:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811198

Answer (score 6):

Best not to use /mnt, but create a new /mnt/data  or just /data. You may want other mounts in /mnt and those would remove the data partitions (I have done that in testing a /mnt of something).

After you copy all your data folders like Music to the partition on your other drive.
Unmount your temporary mount if it is just temporary.

NOTE: The mount point can be anywhere. If it's in your /home or /media folders it will show up under "Places". If it's directly off "/" or /mnt it will not. I prefer /mnt so I do not see it other than thru the links.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/data
sudo chown $USER:$USER /mnt/data
sudo chmod -R a+rwX /mnt/data
```

Note: The big "X" will also not make files executable unless they were executable to begin with.
find your UUID, entry below shows example with UUID, must be yours

```
sudo blkid
```

Edit fstab with your UUID, use ext4 or depending on format:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab

UUID=a55e6335-616f-4b10-9923-e963559f2b05 /mnt/data ext4 relatime 0 2
```

Verify entry is ok, if no errors it is, if manually mounted as above unmount first:

```
sudo mount -a
```

from home  (cd ~ if not at home) so default location of link is in /home/$USER
 cannot have duplicate entries, so move current to temporary location, repeat for each folder you want to move.

```
mv Music oldMusic
```

Music is then also the folder in the partition mounted as /mnt/data

```
ln -s /mnt/data/Music
```

Or link all folders with one command:

for i in `echo /mnt/data/*`;do ln -s $i; done

You can delete oldMusic after you confirm everything is ok.

it then should be this with l as first char for link.

```
fred@Z170N:~$ ll
lrwxrwxrwx  1 fred fred     15 Jun 10  2017 Music -> /mnt/data/Music/
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer oldfred.

It is way too complicated for me. What is /mnt? Is it more than just a name/label (like /donut)? How can I change it? I am confused with "mount-point". I have the normal home folders (on ssd) like music. Is this supposed to be the mount point. Or do i have to create a new folder on the hdd and that is the mount point? Why is my hdd now copywritten?? I copied the data of my old laptop there, now I can only read.

Comment: I changed something in fstab. I tried to mount a folder there from hdd. Without UUID, just /dev/sda2/pictures. I am not sure if it is double mounted now, because of additional /mnt (also /dev/sda2). I wanted to try it, now Ubuntu won`t boot at all....

I´m feeling like a baby trying to drive a car. That´s the shit with Linux for inexperienced users... there is a ton of advice and information, but not enough easy step by step solutions (IKEA-like).... Can I save my system somehow???

Comment: If you edit fstab, you have to run the `sudo mount -a` as posted above to make sure there are no errors before rebooting. These are the defaults for file structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard Windows just has c: or D: etc.Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info