# How to boost boot time and application with a SSD?

Tags: boot, files, ssd, system

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my HDD. The Windows boot loader is in SSD, and the mount point of /boot is also in SSD. But the root directory "/" is mounted at HDD. For a few days, I feel like ubuntu boots really slow, and so do application. I can spare some SSD because I don't use Windows frequently, but what should I do to make use of that part of SSD?
I know little about how linux arrange its files on disk, so any point is appreciated!

Comment: How much space can you spare on your SSD?

Comment: Post these above in your question: `sudo parted -l` and mount your partitions that are not mounted and run `df -h`. I like to keep / (root) on SSD, but have all my data on my HDD in /mnt/data and folders linked into /home. When I still had Windows I had two data partitions, one NTFS and one ext4. http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/921778/windows-10-dual-boot-ubuntu-on-ssd-and-data-on-hdd